# Should subwin windows be one size larger than content

Tags: python, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I have the piece of code below which wouldn't work unless `n_rows > 3` or `n_cols > 3`. Otherwise I get this error:

```sh
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "script.py", line 16, in <module>
        curses.wrapper(main)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/curses/__init__.py", line 105, in wrapper
        return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
      File "script.py", line 10, in main
        window.addstr(2, 2, '2')
    _curses.error: addwstr() returned ERR
```

This type of error normally happens when printing outside window (which isn't the case here).

```py
    def main(stdscr):
        n_rows = 3
        n_cols = 3
        window = stdscr.subwin(n_rows, n_cols, 0, 0)
        window.addstr(0, 0, '0')
        window.addstr(1, 1, '1')
        window.addstr(2, 2, '2')
    
        stdscr.getch()
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        curses.wrapper(main)
```

My question is what explains the necessity for window to be one size larger for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is printing at the lower-right corner of a window and returns an error because it cannot wrap (or scroll up).

The [`addch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Adding-characters) manpage says

> - If scrollok is not enabled, writing a character at the lower  right
>   margin  succeeds.   However, an error is returned because it is not
>   possible to wrap to a new line

and [`scrollok`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_outopts.3x.html#h3-scrollok) (which is false unless explicitly set):

> The **`scrollok`** option controls what happens when the cursor of  a  window
> is  moved  off  the edge of the window or scrolling region, either as a
> result of a newline action on the bottom line, or typing the last character of the last line.  If disabled, (bf is *`FALSE`*), the cursor is left
> on the bottom line.  If enabled, (bf is *`TRUE`*), the window  is  scrolled
> up one line (Note that to get the physical scrolling effect on the terminal, it is also necessary to call **`idlok`**).

Comment: I ended up using `insstr()` instead of `addstr()` as it's doesn't move the cursor after writing to the screen (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28156192/2228912))